# Show $|\sum z_i a_i|\le |\sum (|z_i| a_i)|$ where $z_i$ is complex sequence and $a_i$ is real sequence

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers

Show $|\sum z_i a_i|\le |\sum (|z_i| a_i)|$ where $z_i$ is complex sequence and $a_i$ is real sequence.

Attempt: $|\sum z_i a_i|^2 =(\sum z_i^* a_i)(\sum z_i a_i)=\sum z_i^* z_j a_i a_j=\sum Re(z_i^* z_j) a_i a_j$. But I cannot proceed from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false. For example $|(1) 1+(i) (-1)| >|(1) (1)+(1)(-1)|$.

[Take $z_1=1,z_2=i,a_1=1$ and $a_2=-1$].